# "ParameterExpression of type 'B' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'"

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an object and want to call a function on all "String" type (recursively). For example:

```
        public class A : ILo
        {
            public string Prop1 { get; set; }
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public B BInfo { get; set; }
            public List<C> ListOfC { get; set; }
        }

        public class B : ILo
        {
            public string Prop2 { get; set; }
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
        }
        public class C : ILo
        {
            public string Prop3 { get; set; }
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
        }


--------------
    public T Translate<T>(T need) where T: class
    {
        if (need == null) return default(T);
        var t = need.GetType();
        var props = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (var propInfo in props)
        {
            if (propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(t);
                Expression propExp = Expression.Property(pe, propInfo);
                Expression<Func<T, string>> eFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(propExp, pe);
                var locVal = DoTranslation(need, eFunc, ((ILo)need).GetId());

                propInfo.SetValue(need, locVal);
            }
            else if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                var temp = Convert.ChangeType(propInfo.GetValue(need), propInfo.PropertyType);
                Translate(temp);
            }
            else if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                // do Translate for all items
            }
        }
        return need;
    }
```

Translate function work perfectly when I call it for "B" or "C" and work good when I call it for "A" but when it wants call A.BInfo  I  get an error (on "Expression> eFunc = Expression.Lambda>(propExp, pe);").

My error is: 
"ParameterExpression of type 'B' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'"

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on? What is the type of the exception? Can you cut this down to a smaller example? How are you calling `DoSomething`  (ie what is the generic parameter you are passing)? Is the fact that `DoSomething` is Generic actually relevant - do you get the same problem if you convert it to a method that takes a specific type?

Comment: The exception is telling you you're creating a `Expression<Func<object, string>>`, but attempting to give it a parameter of type `B`. That cannot possibly work. `Func<object, string>` needs a parameter of type `object`. But without knowing what this is supposed to do, it's impossible to tell what the proper way of fixing it is. Maybe you should be ensuring `Expression<Func<B, string>>` is used. Maybe you should ensure the parameter is of type `object`. Maybe it should be something inbetween.

Comment: @Chris Now, It is a simple example. thanks alot.

Comment: @hvd I want to call DoTranslation for all Generic Objects that implements ILo

Comment: @hvd When I change Expression<Func<T, string>> --> Expression<Func<object, string>>, I got an error on Translate(B) that work perfectly before.

Comment: @User128912 Well yeah... the types are `object` and `B` in the specific call that was causing problems, not in all calls, and it shouldn't be changed in such a way that it becomes one type in all calls.